# How to deploy a Celery worker on Google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Celery worker need to deploy to Google app engine, is it possible?
I intend to use one app for my main Django app, one app for Celery worker and one Rabbitmq service (it supported by Google cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Celery task queue I would suggest using  App Engine [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/).

You can use [Push queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/):

> Push queues run tasks by delivering HTTP requests to App Engine worker
>   services. They dispatch these requests at a reliable, steady rate and
>   guarantee reliable task execution. Because you can control the rate at
>   which tasks are sent from the queue, you can control the workers'
>   scaling behavior and hence your costs.

and [Pull queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/pull/):

> Pull queues do not dispatch tasks at all. They depend on other worker
>   services to "lease" tasks from the queue on their own initiative. Pull
>   queues give you more power and flexibility over when and where tasks
>   are processed, but they also require you to do more process
>   management. When a task is leased the leasing worker declares a
>   deadline. By the time the deadline arrives the worker must either
>   complete the task and delete it or the Task Queue service will allow
>   another worker to lease it.

Comment: This answer is based on deprecated technology.

Comment: @DaanLuttik so what do you suggest we use instead of Taskqueue?

Comment: @UdayReddy I believe that the scenario that the original question describes is possible. You can also consider [pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub).